# Cannot select faces that I created already

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

Hi I cannot select any of the faces that I created. Below Im trying to select what will be the window of a small room but if I click all big face is selected.

This is the way I did it the window and the rectangular face just on top of it:selecting the top edge of the big left face -> subdivide, after the bottom edge -> subdivide and finally selecting vertices of top and bottom created hit F key to connect.

[image: Created just -> subdivide, after the bottom edge -> subdivide and finally selecting vertices of top and bottom created -> F]

Do you know what's going on here?

Small update:I moved the face and looks like the edges that I created subdividing the top and bottom edges from this left wall are "disconnected" from the face here the image.
[image]

Thanks.
Regards.
Jose

Comment: You have some doubled up faces there. Try deleting the Selected face.

Comment: Hi David there is no doubled, I checked already. Thanks. Its like doesnt recognize as faces the way I subdivided it.

Comment: Sosi, when you make/fill individual lines on an existing face that's all you're doing.  A good test is to (in Edit Mode) select that face and see if the entire area is highlited.  If it is you've still got the original face. With it still highlited, press X and select "Faces Only" and that gets rid of it without destroying it's edges.  You're then free to fill in those other faces, leaving the window vacant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is delete the selected face on the image you posted, then create each individual face separately, selecting the edges that form one and pressing the F key, do this for every face.
See the images below for an example:

**1) Empty edges**

[image: empty]

**2) Selection of the edges**

[image: edges]

**3) After pressing the F key**

[image: face]